# Sitecore came up with GraphQL in 9.2, so internally does they use Sitecore API?

Tags: sitecore-api, graphql

What does GraphQL use internally to query the Sitecore items?

Answer (score 4):

I want to make it clear that Sitecore did not invent or create GraphQL. GraphQL is a pre-existing standard: https://graphql.org/

The Sitecore GraphQL API is an implementation of that standard with some Sitecore-specific bits.

As I understand it, the endpoint is running C# code on the server that is defined for schemas and extenders. It wraps around Sitecore's context database, and ultimately at the very bottom of the layers the content queries are calling the native Sitecore Item API for single Item requests, and the ContentSearch API for searches.

Make sure to take a look at the examples for customization on the JSS site to get an idea of the various things like endpoints, schemas, extenders, etc.: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/graphql/graphql-overview

Comment: Hi @jason St, thank you for your answer and my bad of putting the question wrong.. instead of using the word implemented I used came up with as I am already aware of GraphQL org, OK now the actual part, If they are again implementing and making use of SitecoreItemAPI and ContentsearchAPI how this is faster when compared to traditional SitecoreAPI was my question? any help would be really appreciated

Comment: @Sudhakar_Mangalarapu if you have further questions, please open another post.

Comment: You have changed the purpose of your question now that you have an answer. Please use a new question for your question so you do not invalidate answers.